# Manual Control of R legend with ggplot2

Tags: r, graphics

I've got a (x,y) data set and I want to visualize the following:

- The scatter plot of the points
- The linear least squares fitting
- A reference line

I'm able to accomplish these tasks with ggplot using geom_point, geom_smooth, and geom_abline.  However, I can't see how to add a legend that lets me annotate what the three graphical objects mean.  Also, my data set is just a vector of x values and a vector of y values (not a data frame).

Here is an example of the code:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(100)

x = seq(-5, 1, length=50)

c0= 2 
c1 = 1

y = c0 + c1*x + rnorm(length(x),sd = 0.5)

# Fit a linear model, y~x means y is the response 
# variable to the x predictor variable
gp <- ggplot(mapping = aes(x=x,y=y))  
gp <- gp + geom_point(col="black") 
gp <- gp + geom_smooth(method=lm, formula = y~x, color="darkred", fill="red") 
gp <- gp + geom_abline(intercept = 0.,slope = 0., lty="dashed", col="black")
plot(gp)
```

And I would like to include a legend identifying the data, the least squares fit, and the horizontal line included for reference.

Comment: There is no function in ggplot2 to do this. You can position text on the plot using `annotate`, see here http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/annotate.html

Comment: It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you provide [a complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question. Something we can easily pick up and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question.